# Query to find out delta in columns

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I want to write a query which will read same column from two table 1. from master 2. from audit table. and return column name along with new and old value of it if there is a change in value for example.

master query: `select issue_date,issue_price,issue_entity from voucher where voucher_id=x;` 
audit query : `select issue_date,issue_price,issue_entity from voucher_audit  where version=2 and voucher_id=x;`

Note both voucher and voucher_audit has the same table structure except the version number is extra in audit tables.

then result should be

```
column_name  old_value new_value
issue_price  36        38 
issue_date   01/03/14  02/03/14
```

Comment: Without knowing the unique Key of master there's no way to join back to the audit.  Without knowing the audit table structure and how it handles multiple changes to the same master record, I can't think of how to do this.  With regards to getting the results based on column, it would require using Dynamic SQL and use of the system table all_tab_Cols to find all column values in the table, and then dynamically generate SQL and then execute comparisons only showing differences. Too many unknowns to be able to effectively answer.

Comment: i have update the query with pkey, now we can identify the record in both the tables

Answer (score 0):

You should get all columns that have identical name in both tables. Then you should get the value of each column using dynamic SQL.

```
DECLARE
  input_voucher_id VARCHAR2(100) := '&voucher_id';
  input_version VARCHAR2(100):='&version';
  CURSOR c_common_column IS
    SELECT u.COLUMN_NAME
    FROM   user_tab_cols u
    WHERE  u.TABLE_NAME = 'VOUCHER'
           AND EXISTS
     (SELECT 1
            FROM   user_tab_cols u1
            WHERE  u1.TABLE_NAME = 'VOUCHER_AUDIT'
                   AND u1.COLUMN_NAME = u.COLUMN_NAME);
  v_first_sql        VARCHAR2(1000):='' ;
  v_second_sql       VARCHAR2(1000) :=''; 
  first_table_value  VARCHAR2(100) := '';
  second_table_value VARCHAR2(100) := '';
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line('Column Name,old_value,new_value');
  FOR x IN c_common_column   LOOP
    v_first_sql:='SELECT '||x.COLUMN_NAME|| ' from voucher where voucher_id=:voucher_id';
    v_second_sql :='SELECT '||x.COLUMN_NAME|| ' from voucher_audit where voucher_id=:voucher_id and version = :version';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_first_sql
      INTO first_table_value
      USING  input_voucher_id;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_second_sql
      INTO second_table_value
      USING  input_voucher_id, input_version;
    if first_table_value != second_table_value then 
        dbms_output.put_line(x.COLUMN_NAME ||','|| first_table_value || ',' ||
                         second_table_value);
    end if;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: thats wonderful, i will try this tomorrow, once more question can we return the output in a cursor so that i will use that cursor in ireport as we do in simple select query also, i have requirement to compare more than 10 queries will this solution work fine for that too?

Comment: or if we can use the functionality of views to get the output of the above pl sql....   Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: you may create a pipeline function that returns a collection of a type. Then you can use the function in select statement(see http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/pipelined-table-functions.php).